# How can I add two different programs of bldc motor and servo motor in one so that they work in parallel?

Tags: arduino-uno

This is for the servo motor:

```
#include <Servo.h> //Servo library

Servo servo_test;
//initialize a servo object for the connected servo
int angle = 0;

void setup() {
  servo_test.attach(9);
}

void loop() {
  for(angle = 0; angle < 180; angle += 1) {
    servo_test.write(angle);
    delay(15);
  }
  delay(1000);
  for(angle = 180; angle>=1; angle-=5) {
    servo_test.write(angle);
    delay(5);
  }
  delay(1000);
}
```

This is for the bldc motor with esc:

```
#include <Servo.h>

Servo esc_signal;

void setup() {
  esc_signal.attach(12);
  esc_signal.write(30);
  delay(3000);
}

void loop() {
  esc_signal.write(55);
  delay(15);
}
```

Comment: First thing, read the [Blink without delay](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BlinkWithoutDelay) Arduino tutorial, then remove all calls to `delay()` from your programs.

Comment: Actually, this kind of task is not inconsistent with use of blocking delays, but they need to be used with more coordination and care.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on how the code is driven. The simplest would be to simply run loop1 and loop2 in the new loop.

Comment: But that would make the code execute serially not in parallel as the OP requested.  You can't do parallel on an Arduino.

Answer (score -1):

Try out this code. It may be helpful.

```
#include <Servo.h> //Servo library

Servo servo_test;  //initialize a servo object for the connected servo
int angle = 0;

Servo esc_signal;

void setup()
{
  servo_test.attach(9);

  esc_signal.attach(12);
  esc_signal.write(30);
  delay(3000);
}

void loop()
{
  servoFun();
  bldcFun();
}

void servoFun()
{
  for(angle = 0; angle < 180; angle += 1)
  {
      servo_test.write(angle);
      delay(15);
  }
  delay(1000);

  for(angle = 180; angle>=1; angle-=5)
  {
      servo_test.write(angle);
      delay(5);
  }
  delay(1000);
}

void bldcFun()
{
  esc_signal.write(55);
  delay(15); 
}
```

Comment: No.  That won't do what is desired *at all*.